# How do I pass 2 lists into Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, parallel-processing

How do I pass 2 lists into `Parallel.ForEach`?

Example:

```
List<Person> a = new List<Person>() { new Person(), new Person(), new Person() };
List<Car> b = new List<Car>() { new Car(), new Car(), new Car() };

//PSEUDO CODE
Parallel.ForEach(a, b, (person, car) => {
    //WORK ON person, WORK ON car
});
```

I would prefer to avoid encapsulating Person and Car into Object container. Is this possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4 (which you probably are) and you're trying to pair the first `Person` with the first `Car` etc, you can just use [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx):

```
List<Person> a = new List<Person>() { new Person(), new Person(), new Person() };
List<Car> b = new List<Car>() {} { new Car(), new Car(), new Car() };
var zipped = a.Zip(b, (person, car) => new { person, car });

Parallel.ForEach(zipped, pair => {
    Person person = pair.person;
    Car car = pair.car;
});
```

Answer (score 11):

You are looking for `Enumerable.Zip`